# Calling $digest on a jasmine test works only the first time

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test the behavior of a 'watch' on my scope. But the problem is it's called only once. Check the fiddle below. And strangely, i noticed that if you put the variables in the controller's $scope rather than on the controller itself (aka $scope.name vs vm.name) it actually works.

***Using vm (not working): http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/60/***

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
(function (angular) {
    // Create module
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    // Controller which counts changes to its "name" member
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = 'Superhero';
        vm.counter = 0;
        $scope.$watch('vm.name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            vm.counter = vm.counter + 1;
        });
    }]);      
})(angular);



// ---SPECS-------------------------

describe('myApp', function () {
    var scope,
    controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
        it('sets the name', function () {
            expect(controller.name).toBe('Superhero');
        });

        it('watches the name and updates the counter', function () {
            expect(controller.counter).toBe(0);
            controller.name = 'Batman';
            scope.$digest();
            expect(controller.counter).toBe(1);
            controller.name = 'Superman';            
            scope.$digest();
            expect(controller.counter).toBe(2);
        });
    });



});
```

***Using $scope (works): http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/61/***

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
(function (angular) {
    // Create module
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    // Controller which counts changes to its "name" member
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {       
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
        });
    }]);      
})(angular);



// ---SPECS-------------------------

describe('myApp', function () {
    var scope,
    controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
        it('sets the name', function () {
            expect(scope.name).toBe('Superhero');
        });

        it('watches the name and updates the counter', function () {
            expect(scope.counter).toBe(0);
            scope.name = 'Batman';
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.counter).toBe(1);
            scope.name = 'Superman';            
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.counter).toBe(2);
        });
    });



});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are watching for a property on the scope, which is not really the case, since you are modifying property in your controller. So change your watch to:-

```
   $scope.$watch(function(){
       return vm.name;
    }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        vm.counter = vm.counter + 1;
    });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZ3OC0?p=preview)**

Another way to make it work is to use `controller as vm` in your test while instantiating the controller, so that controller instance would be attached the scope as a property with name `vm`.

```
        controller = $controller('MyCtrl as vm', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
```

**[Plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/rVzBxB?p=preview)**